# Angular submit post data to Iframe from controller programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

what i am trying to achieve is that i want to load an iframe and send some data using the post method.

I want it to happen programmatically so i don't want a user click.
here is the code that i have come up so far.

In my view i have the following:

```
<form id="submitValues" target="siteFrame" 
   enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  method="POST" action="http://localhost/PHP/dataSender.php">
   <input type="text" name="jwt" ng-model="jwtData"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="name" ng-model="Hiddenname"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="type" ng-model="typeData"/>
</form>

  <iframe name="siteFrame" id="siteFrame" 
        seamless="seamless" onLoad="iframeLoadDone()"></iframe>
```

Note that the target of the form is the iframe.

In my controller i am doing this :

```
$scope.jwtData="someData";
$scope.Hiddenname="someData";
$scope.typeData="someData";
document.getElementById('submitValues').submit();
```

The value in the ng-model are not getting sent, they do show up in the view if i remove the "hidden" value form the inputs.

How to send the values?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: @Blowsie no i did not...I actually went with another method instead submitting data to the iframe..i am submitting the data to a page on the server which then redirects or takes some action..